# USB hub, audio and document scanner causes stuttering

Tags: usb, audio, webcam

I have:

- A cheap USB webcam
- A not so cheap USB "document scanner" (basically a webcam on a stick, by [Ipevo](https://www.ipevo.com/products/vz-r)).  Both this and the webcam have a usb microphone.
- A cheap USB headset (so speaker and microphone)

All are plugged into a cheap USB 3 hub (which has a power supply) which is connected to what should be a USB 3 port on my computer.

When using the document scanner and the usb audio, I get incredibly bad stuttering (the audio will stop outputting for a second, then continue for a few seconds, then repeat).

- It works fine if I use the webcam and usb audio both plugged into the hub
- It works fine if I plug the usb audio directly into my (desktop) computer
- I did a test of copying a large file to a usb memory stick plugged into the hub, while using the document scanner.  This was slightly slower (16mb/s) than when the scanner was inactive (17mb/s) but no obvious stuttering.

So this seems to be a combination of document scanner, hub, and usb audio.  What would cause this?  Is there any fix (except for not using the hub, which slightly defeats the point of me buying it-- to avoid scrabbling under my desk).

Comment: The old phrase "you get what you paid for" springs to mind. Cheap devices contain cheap parts which aren't necessarily up to the job.

Comment: This is very true.  Though here the decidedly "mid-priced" component is the document scanner, which also seems to be the problem...